# Reactstrap dropdown without a select or button

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to build a menu. Something like below:

[image]
I plan to use a simple dropdown menu of bootstrap. However I am not sure how to do it. I have following in my class function render method:

```
<td style={{ width: 20, cursor: "pointer" }}>
  <Dropdown
    toggle={this.toggleMenu}
    isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
  >
    <div>&bull;&bull;&bull;</div>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem>10</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>25</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>50</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>100</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </Dropdown>
</td>
```

And I have following events/variables:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      collapse: false,
      fadeIn: true,
      timeout: 300,
      dropdownOpen: false,
      debug: ""
    };
  }

  toggleMenu(e) {
    alert("sds");
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
  }
```

I dont get any errors and toggleMenu is never called. Am I missing something here?

If I use DropDownToggle it adds a button:
[image]

Comment: The screenshot and your description, does not make it clear what you want to do, and what is the problem, you toggle should work on hover ?

Comment: I want a dropdown menu to appear when I click <div>&bull;&bull;&bull;</div>. That is the tree dot's. The problem is nothing happens when I click the 3 dots.

Comment: `<DropdownToggle>&bull;&bull;&bull;</DropdownToggle>`

Comment: That was my first implementation. But it add's a button (it is like it is implemented as a select button). I jave updated my post with screenshot.

Comment: OK you got me in the right direction. Can you add an answer? I did as you stated using <DropdownToggle tag="div">. The attribute tag can determine what tag that hosts this. That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<div>&bull;&bull;&bull;</div>
```

try using the DropdownToggle component together with the 'tag' property like this:

```
<DropdownToggle tag="text">&bull;&bull;&bull;</DropdownToggle>
```